# cordova-plugin-admob-free: Uncaught (in promise) Interstitial not ready yet

Tags: cordova, cordova-admob

I'm trying to implement interstitial ads in my HTML5 game using cordova-plugin-admob-free.

I use it as follows:

```
var ADMOB_AndroidID = (my Admob ID here);
var ADMOB_iOSID     = "";
var ADMOB_WindowsID = "";

document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', initAdmob );

function initAdmob() {
  var admobid = {};
  if ( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {  // for android & amazon-fireos
    admobid = {
      banner: ADMOB_AndroidID,
      interstitial: ADMOB_AndroidID
    };
  } else if ( /(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {  // for ios
    admobid = {
      banner: ADMOB_iOSID,
      interstitial: ADMOB_iOSID
    };
  } else {  // for windows phone
    admobid = {
      banner: ADMOB_WindowsID,
      interstitial: ADMOB_WindowsID
    };
  }

  admob.interstitial.config({
    id: admobid.interstitial,
    isTesting: true,
    autoShow: false
  })
  admob.interstitial.prepare();

  document.addEventListener('admob.interstitial.events.CLOSE', function(event) {
    admob.interstitial.prepare();
  } );

}
```

Then, after the game has finished, I call

```
admob.interstitial.show();
```

When I run it on the Android emulator (or on a real device), nothing happens when the game finishes and the Chrome debugger shows:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Interstital not ready yet
```

So what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT: Added screenshot of Chrome Console**

My console show this (after I added an eventlistener on LOAD_FAIL of the interstitial):

[image: Chrome Console]

Answer (score 0):

It just started working without me changing anything. Apparently, it takes (quite) a while for an Ad Unit to become active after it has been created. So the above code works.

Just an extra tip: I first made the mistake of using my **App ID** instead of the **Ad Unit ID**. If your ID has a tilde (~) instead of a slash (/), then you are using your App ID. Login to your AdMob account, create an Ad Unit, and use its ID instead.

Answer (score 0):

Had have this one too.

Realized that I never called to

```
admob.interstitial.prepare();
```

After adding, everything works.